# Unable to use update npm or install any npm module on mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, npm, npm-install

```
npm ERR! Darwin 17.2.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "-g" "npm"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND

npm ERR! Cannot find module 'realize-package-specifier'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

When I try to update npm this the error I receive. I get similar errors while performing any npm install/update operation.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the command you're trying to run and in what context: npm project, global context?

Comment: I ran `npm i -g npm`. Initially I tried installing express module in my project for whic I ran `npm install express`. But I still got a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall node via brew ( `brew uninstall node` & `brew install node`). npm ships with Node so you should be good to go. These errors might occur after updating npm, AFAIK this is the safest workaround.

Comment: I'm not sure it's helpful to do this without determining first what the problem is. This is assuming that you're using Homebrew in order to install node, which may not be the case. nvm seems to be quite popular nowadays, and much more versatile as you can maintain and quickly swap between different versions of node, which is extremely useful during development.

Comment: Very true, I've just stated the common and safest way to resolve the issue, he hasn't really stated anything besides the fact that it doesn't work.

Comment: What other information is necessary? I'll share that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I installed `node` using `nvm` and my issue was resolved. [This](http://nodesource.com/blog/installing-node-js-tutorial-using-nvm-on-mac-os-x-and-ubuntu/) is what I followed to do so.